# Any way to hook function into post footer in WordPress (not wp_footer)?

Tags: php, wordpress, hook

You can hook functions into the site footer using the following:

```
function to_footer() {
  $content = 'I am in the footer';
  echo $content;
}

add_action('wp_footer', 'to_footer');
```

But is there a similar approach to add a function inside the post's footer (not site footer) in single page views?

Comment: AFAIK a post doesn't have a footer. It does have a title, and a meta. It is probably plugin or theme dependent - what is the 'post footer'?

Comment: The possibility is in your custom footer call `apply_filter('some function')` and then in your `functions.php` `add_filter(same function)`. I didn't know word-press in depth but may be this will the approach

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest you can get (without changing template files) is this

```
function to_footer($content) 
{
    return $content . 'I am in the footer';
}
add_action('the_content', 'to_footer');
```

This will add your thing after post content

If you do not mind editing your templates, try the following

```
function alt_footer()
{
    do_action('alt_footer');
}
```

in `functions.php` of your theme. Then call `alt_footer()` in your template where you need it, then

```
function to_footer() 
{
    echo 'I am in the footer';
}
add_action('alt_footer', 'to_footer');
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that already and it kind of works, but I would prefer to add stuff even further down not just after the main content.

Comment: This is brilliant! But if I were to create a plugin, this approach wouldn't be user friendly at all. I guess it's template dependant, but is there a way to hook something, let's say, into the post navigation (that's around the area I wanted to hook my plugin)?

Comment: @ynef yeah, it wouldn't be too user friendly, but you can't have it all :) I'm not sure about nav, need to look into the source but even if it works, it'd be kinda template dependent too since not all of themes use nav in the same place under the post, among few other reasons

Comment: Thanks. Chose you as best answer because in the end it helped me achieve what I wanted nicely.